# How to structure an app-game?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone

I have started a project making a game using cocos2d-x and Visual Studio (c++). I was wondering if anyone had any tips on how it should be structured, purely theoretical?

I've already done a decent amount, I have a menu set-up with some buttons etc, I have a player class which i load in when you press play.

Should I have an enemy class? To create and deal with those.
I want to keep track on how many enemies are spawned in so I can do stuff based on that.

How do you recommend I switch between levels?

Also what file format should i store data in?

Looking for theoretical tips about building a game!

best regards,
a fresh face.

Comment: If you had not found the Ray Wenderlich site, you could not possibly have done a single google search !

Comment: I jumped the gun a little by asking this question, I've been to Ray Wenderlich site, but I haven't found excactly what I'm looking for.

Now I am just moving on and following a few tutorials, but I feel this is not the best way to do it and I will have to go back and change everything whenever I know better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search the Internet... what you are asking is very high level.
Just find a tutorial and follow it :)

[This website](http://www.raywenderlich.com/95835/cocos2d-x-tutorial-beginners)  has loads of good stuff.